# What is the difference between TAS and GS?

Tags: airspeed, groundspeed

I'm looking for an explanation of true airspeed and ground speed.

Comment: The difference between them is the wind speed. TAS + Wind = GS

Comment: If you know what the abbreviations mean then this question answers itself!

Answer (score 6):

TAS = True Airspeed = speed that you get on radar gun as airplane flies by, when radar gun is held by someone in gondola of balloon in same airmass (wind motion) as airplane.

GS =Groundspeed = speed that you get on radar gun as airplane flies by, when radar gun is held by someone on ground.

As an example: TAS of 200 knots and a headwind of 20 knots gives a GS of 200-20=180 knots.  That is: the plane travels at 180 knots over ground but the air is flowing past the plane at 200 knots.

Comment: Weird phone screw-up there!

Comment: Feel free to add via editing (or post own); I'm not emotionally attached to ownership of this answer :)

Comment: Edited to fix units and avoid issue with what you "feel" with hand being a better description of IAS than TAS.

Comment: Pythagoras would like to have a word with you about your "GS" definition.

Comment: @JacobKrall - ok I get it.  The radar gun should not be triggered until a/c is flying nearly directly away...

Answer (score 2):

True air speed is the speed in relation to the mass of air you are moving in, and ground speed is the speed in relation to the ground.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer.

TAS is GS without wind. 
GS is TAS with wind factored in.

So, on a no wind day, TAS = GS